# How to trigger and execute an Release Build properly using Jenkins

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, release

we are setting up a Jenkins Server for our maven based, multi module software project. So far, we have set up a Multibranch Pipeline with a short Jenkinsfile. The build works as expected.

Performing a Release consists currently of 10 manual steps and development skills are required to perform most of them (including knowledge of git and mvn). I would like to have a one click solution integrated in Jenkins. The user should enter some informations about the release and the rest is done on full auto.

I found a Release Plugin for Jenkins, but it seems to be of no big use, because it does not play well with the Jenkins Pipeline idea. I'm confused what the best practice for our setup may be.

In my opinion, we are using a quite "modern" toolset, e.g. Jenkins Pipeline as Code, git, github, mvn. But I can't figure out a/the "clean" way to trigger a release.

Can you provide me with some god resources that show me a general approach or maybe you could outline your solution?

I know the question is not very precise and will probably be downvoted but I just don't see where to get reliable informations about the topic.

Best Regards
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I have been kind of blind. The solution is simple. The pipeline can have a section parameters. When starting a manual build, the user is prompted to enter these values. You can use the values later throughout the pipeline for whatever you want. In case the build is trigger automatically, the default values are used an no user interaction is necessary.

Thomas